# How to restrict project admin only to create new repository, the master branch in azure devops

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, branching-and-merging

Also i need to know how to make project admin to get notification when a contributor makes a pull request in azure devops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to restrict project admin only to create new repository, the
>   master branch in azure devops

It's is not possible to modify any Permissions to `Project Admin` by default Project Admin has all the permissions (As the name indicates he/she will be the project admin)

*You will see the below error when you tried to modify the permission*

[image]

> Also i need to know how to make project admin to get notification when
>   a contributor makes a pull request in azure devops.

`ProjectSetting`->`Notification`->`New Subscription`->`Code(git)`->`A pull Request is created or updated`

[image]

Under the `Deliver to` you have the options called

1. Members of xxx by role
2. Team Preference
3. Custom Email address
4. Members of xxx Team
5. SOAP

[image]

You can set this to a `custom email address` and point the project admin email address there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer expect same again please,but mistake from my side in asking,what i actually wanted to know was that only the project admin and NO ONE ELSE should be able to create new repo for a project as well as master branch. other contributors should only be able to create dev branch and not allow them to merge to master also. Second question also,what i want to know is if another contributor makes a commit to a dev branch,i noticed the project admin was not getting notification for pull request neither was the project admin able to see the dev branch, i need that to happen.

Comment: @Salman Regarding the first question, you need to configure the Repo level security,see my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510424/7073340), configure the required permissions under the repo and inherit the permission in the branch level. Regarding the notification my answer will be same as it will work for your case too.