# How to permit customer to only read specific branch in VSTS/Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a `VSTS/Azure` DevOps project with a git repository containing different customer branches. I would like to permit each customer to read-only their own branch. How can I achieve this?

The access control settings do not allow me to set read permissions on specific branches, only on entire repositories. So is it perhaps possible to have a separate repository for each customer that automatically mirrors just the corresponding branch in the `master` repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the permission directly in branches (branch level). However, you can inherit/modify the permissions from the repo level to branch level.

[See my similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510424/7073340)

As you stated in your question. You should create separate repos for different customer where you can control the permissions.