# Project wide repository permission

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is it possible to have an Azure repo policy across an entire project? For instance I would like to enforce branch folders but would like it to happen upon repository creation instead of doing it manually afterwards.

Enforcing branch folders in a single repo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=vsts&tabs=browser

Comment: Please see my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509065/azure-devops-default-permissions/52510424#52510424)

Comment: Thanks @Jayendran , I was hoping for something higher than the repo permissions (ie. Project permissions), but I guess those don't exist.